# Can we pass object like textbox to a function?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanna ask about winforms. 
Is it possible to pass object like TextBox to a function that we can call it "Checker Validation" ? 
because I'm too lazy check 1 by 1 on every textbox so I'm curious about how to check it with a function

```
public void checker(object)
{
    if(Object.Text == ""){ Object.BackColor = Color.Red;}
    else{Object.BackColor = Color.White;}

}
public void textbox_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     checker(object);
}
```

i have no idea to input the object textbox on a function @.@

Comment: You might want to look into whether there are already validation systems available that you can make use of, rather than writing one yourself (which here, seems to be about mandatory inputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
public void checker(TextBox txtBox)
{
   if(textbox == null)
   {
      return;
    }

    if(txtBox.Text == "")
    {
       txtBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
      txtBox.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

}
public void textbox_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     checker(sender as TextBox);
}
```

Comment: so sender is a object which contain value on form? @.@ and btw thanks for your answer ! it's work on me

Comment: Though we were both correct, props to Mohit for the really through answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. basically just make the param to your function a textbox...

```
private void Checktext(textbox mytext) 
{ 
    if (mytext.Text=="whatever") 
    { } 
    else 
    { } 
}
```

Thats psudo code off top of my head, but it will get you there.